# support for dask docker images in private container registry

Tags: docker, dask

I was wondering if there is any support for this out yet - might just be me not knowing how to use the API.

Found an open git issue related to this(specific case), https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/issues/93. Not exactly the same though.

I am working on the Azure platform, but this could have been a private docker hub repo I suppose. Pulling public repos have not been an issue, but when pulling an image from private Azure Container Registry the provisioning of a remote cluster gets stuck on "creating scheduler".

context:
I am initiating the dask cluster through dask_cloudprovider AzureVMCluster.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue, but it seems they only support pulling from public repositories.

Comment: Unfortunately no :/